# How to chose the Facebook page will post using php-graph-sdk

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I have some pages I am administrator. I have used php-graph-sdk as login in my websites and now I wish to be able to post content in the feed of the pages I admin using this sdk.

The http way is trough post request to url "https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/feed" with data as post fields. Data will include the message, of course, and page-id page-access-token etc.. The php-graph-sdk documentation, and the examples around the web, shows a code like this:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
  ]);

$linkData = [
  'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
  'message' => 'User provided message',
  ];

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $linkData, '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

I have only the app-id app-secret and access-token (I suppose is the page-access-token). There is no page-id, how do I set witch page to use?

By the way, I am reading the docs in GitHub. The methods don't have fully documentation about those arrays that will be different for the kind of content (link, image, text only...). I have to get some information in examples. Where is this documentation?

Comment: The official Graph API documentation is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/

Comment: _"how do I set witch page to use?"_ - you don't need to set it, because `/me` automatically resolves to whatever user or page the access token belongs to - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview#me

Comment: @CBroe I was thinking about this "me". It seems I just have to replace it by page-id. I don't like this guessing methodology, and the documentation have partial translate to portuguese, this disturbs my understanding, you know, that's why I am asking simple things here.